# biostring() no error message but actually did make it

Tags: r

I have a txt file and already read into R as a list. But when I do biostring and matchpattern, it could read as biostring. Here is what I did.

```
seq<-read.delim("sequence.txt",skip=1,header=F)
> head(seq)
AATTGTCCTTATTAATTGACGATGCTATATTATTAGTCTTTCCGACATTA
1 ATATCAAAGCTATGCGGTGTTGTACTGAACCGAGAAATATTTGTTAATGG
2 ATCTAAGTTTATGTTTGGCACTGGATCAGTTTGACGTCGTGCATTACTCG
3 CTATTGCTTTATCAAATTCGTTTTCTCCGACTGGTTTGTTGTTTTTTATG
4 TGTAAAGAATGCATATAACTAGGAACAGAAAATCGCCCGCTAGTGAAATT
5 GTGATATTCTGAATCTTTCCGCTGTAAGCGCTTTAAGTTTGTTGCAATTA
6 AGTGGGACGATGGAGGTGGGGGTAGACTGCTATTGTAAATTCCAACACCC
> nchar(seq)
AATTGTCCTTATTAATTGACGATGCTATATTATTAGTCTTTCCGACATTA 
                                      20379411 
> seq1<-BString("seq",start=1,nchar=NA)
> bd<-DNAString("CAGGTAG")
> zld<-matchPattern(bd,seq1, max.mismatch=0)
> zld
Views on a 3-letter BString subject
subject: seq
views: NONE
```

what went wrong? Why it can only read 3 letters?
Thank you very much for the help!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a BString object that contains the *string* "seq", rather than the contents of the `seq` variable. I think you want to read the data in as a character vector (not data frame)

```
seq <- readLines("Sequence.txt")[-1]
```

Then create a DNAStringSet (if each line is meant to be a difference sequence)

```
dna <- DNAStringSet(seq)
```

or a singe DNAString (if the multiple lines are meant to represent a single sequence)

```
dna <- DNAString(paste(seq, collapse=""))
```

Alternatively, perhaps you are reading a [FASTA file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format) and that line you skip is actually the sequence identifier "> some|id", in which case simply

```
dna <- readDNAStringSet("Sequence.txt")
```

It's better to ask questions about Bioconductor packages on the [Bioconductor mailing list](http://bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/mailform/) (no subscription required)

Comment: if I use readLines, I cannot skip 1st row. error message: Error in readLines("sequence.txt", skip = 1) : unused argument (skip = 1)

Comment: @lxcfuji then drop the line after reading it in; I updated the response

Comment: never mind! i used readDNAStringSet and it works. forgive me for asking stupid question, what is FASTA file and what is ">some|id"

Comment: @lxcfuji FASTA is a simple text format used to represent sequences; I added a link.